# Pre and post multiplication by a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume we have a projection matrix $P$ ($P=P^\top$, $P=P^2$) and a matrix $A$ which is not necessarily positive definite. I would like to know if it is possible to relate the spectral radius of the matrix $PAP$ to the spectral radius of the matrix $A$. For example, is it correct to say
$$\rho(PAP)\leq\rho(A)?$$
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is hermitian and the entries of $P$ are real, $P A P$ is also hermitian. Then [we have](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect6.pdf)
$$\|A\|=\rho(A)\\
\|P A P\|=\rho(P A P)\\
\|P A P\|\leq \|P\|\|A\|\|P\|\leq \|A\|\\
\rho(P A P)\leq \rho(A)$$
where the norm is the induced norm a.k.a. operator norm.

In the non-hermitian case, this is false. Here is a counterexample:
$$A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
 a_1 & a_2 \\
 -\frac{a_1^2}{4 a_2} & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]\\
p=\left[
\begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
Then $\rho(A)=a_1/2$ and $\rho(P A P)=a_1$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm interested in the case where $A$ is not necessarily Hermitian.

Comment: I added a counterexample in the non-Hermitian case

Comment: Thank you for your response!!